# Detecting Physical Network Addresses Reliably

Tags: debian, networkcard

I'm trying to find a way to list physical (aka MAC) addresses for all network cards/interfaces attached to a certain host. The problem is, I want this functionality on my Debian live (squeeze) USB image which is plugged into many different boxes with widely diverse hardware. So the wireless driver (for example) isn't always available on my USB stick, and thus I can't obtain the physical address from `ifconfig`.

I was under the impression that I could achieve this by querying `/sys/class/net/*/address` where `*` is the interface name in question. But this is not the case. I think there should be a way of querying the hardware for the physical address even if the device driver is not installed.

So my questions are:

1. Is it actually possible to query the physical address of a network device even if its device driver isn't installed?
2. If it's possible, how?

Comment: I'm not sure this is always possible. In a lot of case, you have to inject a firmware to have the card switched on so without any driver nor firmware, you can still have the model and vendor, which give the first bytes of the MAC address, but the entire address, I doubt it.

Comment: Hmmm. But PXE clients report their MAC address to the PXE/TFTP server so it's accessible at boot time. I'm thinking there should be a way from the user space interface to the kernel.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's accessible from the BIOS for the interfaces which are usable for PXE. This is not the case for all interfaces. Usually, you can't boot on PXE from a wireless interface. And those are the interfaces you may have driver problems with. Wired interface are almost always correctly supported by a standard Debian kernel.

Comment: This makes sense. I'll leave the question around for a while for confirmation/rebuttal from someone else. If neither comes, and if you want to move your comments to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @JosephR. It is not supported. PXE is a special case as the driver is in the firmware and is platform independent. You can use something like serial number for your asset management. Btw. tools like facter can automatically report details about the system, including mac addresses

Comment: @UlrichDangel Way to glean the use-case from context :) `facter` looks interesting indeed, but all it does is pretty up the output of tools like `dmidecode` and `lsb_release`, which is kind of what I'm doing already.

Comment: The interesting thing is, `facter` reports `virtual=>false` on my VBox installation of `squeeze` :)

Comment: @JosephR. the important thing with facter is the integration with other services, especially puppet and that you don't have to gather all the output yourself. facter & puppet for example are integrated into foreman which is a solution for the complete lifecycle management, e.g. deployment of servers (virtualised & bare metal), de-provisioning etc. the observation re. `virtual => false` is due to imvirt or something else reporting the wrong values

Comment: @UlrichDangel I can't thank you enough for directing my attention to `puppet` and `foreman`. I'm currently overhauling the IT infrastructure at work and I had many scalability and centralization concerns that `puppet` blew right out the window. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in a reliable way. Network cards need to be supported by a driver and sometimes need to be injected a firmware to start up, and thus, to be able to answer the query for their physical address.

Almost all the wired interfaces are supported by a standard Debian kernel (at least, I don't know any wired interface which is not, they are quite simple and standard). Wireless interfaces are much more complicated and not all are supported. They sometimes need proprietary firmware which is not packaged within a Debian installation by default.

EDIT

For those who are interested in the technical details, I figured out how the Linux kernel knows the MAC address of a specific interface. There is a field in the structure `netdevice` each networking driver uses to register itself to the driver. This field must be filled by the driver before it register the device into the kernel. For further details, see `linux/netdevice.h` and *Linux Device Drivers*, 3rd edition, by Jonathan Corbet, Greg Kroah-Hartman, and Alessandro Rubini, section 17.3 (http://makelinux.net/ldd3/).

Comment: Thanks for the informative edit. Unfortunately, I already used my only upvote :)